# Fullview image display with delete option

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

Currently I have implemented a fullview image display using recyclerview, horizontal scrolling. The problem is delete button is in every view of recyclerview item.
I wanted to implement the delete button in activity and onclick of delete button, I want to delete the currently displayed image. I am not able to get the position of currently displayed view of recyclerview in activity. Any help will be thankful. If there is any other approach other than using recyclerview, even that will be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

According to Standard approach place delete button in each recyclerview item.
 it is easy to get position of any imageview that you want to delete.
 So please don't implement delete button outside of recyclerview.

Comment: Thank you for reply

Comment: if my answer is helpful to you then please accept and upvote so it will benefit to other users